# Calling multiple handler methods in react js onSubmit

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, axios

I am working on a React JS project which uses a search form component with an onSubmit. I want to call multiple search handler methods which makes Axios calls to multiple backend APIs at the same time. I am using a class component, my onSubmit calls a searchHandler method which contains multiple axios calls to the backend. But when I submit the form I get an error: [frontend error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fWdc.png)

This is my search handler function which my onSubmit calls, it contains two Axios calls:

```html
applicationSearchHandler(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    console.log(this.state.number, this.state.orgChoice);

    LoanAppDataService.getPromoCodeExpiryInfo(
      this.state.orgChoice,
      this.state.promoCode,
      this.state.number
    )
      .then((response) => {
        if (response && response.data && response.data.length > 0) {
          console.log(response.data[0].applicationId);

          this.setState((state) => ({
            ...this.state,
            expiryStatusMessage: response.data[0].message,
            isSearched: true,
            error: false,
          }));
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        this.setState({
          error: !this.state.error,
          errorAlert: "",
          isSearched: false,
        });
      });

    LoanAppDataService.getCorrectPromoCodeInfoEmailAndOrgId(
      this.state.emailId,
      this.state.orgChoice
    )
      .then((response) => {
        this.setState((state) => ({
          associatedPromoMessage: response.data[0].message,
          isSearched: true,
          error: false,
        }));
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        this.setState({
          error: !this.state.error,
          errorAlert: "",
          isSearched: false,
        });
      });

    this.setState((state) => ({
      ...this.state,
      number: "",
      customerName: "",
      orgChoice: "",
    }));

    const isValid = this.validateSsn();
  }
```

This is how my onSubmit looks like:

```html
<form onSubmit={this.applicationSearchHandler}>
```

I don't exactly know how to rectify this error, I tried multiple approaches but nothing seems to be working for now.

Answer (score 0):

You get an error In this part of your code

expiryStatusMessage: response.data[0].message

Most Probably response.data[0] is null or undefined and this code tries to find a message from null, So it gives Error

You can use nullish operator here like that

expiryStatusMessage: response.data[0]?.message

Comment: I did that but my state value is not updated as I receive information from the backend, it still remains undefined. also, I get an error in this part of the code: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fWdc.png

Comment: if response.data[0] is null, you can't get message. Nullish operator may not work properly for every browser and versions. Can you try   response.data[0]==undefined ? null (or default value for this state) : response.data[0].message

Comment: I tried that, but that didn't work. My app crashes everytime I do that